# Can't set up Reaction Commerce on MacOS 10.13.2

Tags: javascript, docker, meteor, docker-compose, reaction-commerce

I am trying to set up Reaction Commerce by following, step-by-step, what is written in [those docs](https://docs.reactioncommerce.com/docs/installation-reaction-platform).

But I'm stuck at the very beginning, when I run the `make` command, here's what I get:
[image]

### Steps to Reproduce

(on MacOS 10.13.2 High Sierra)

1. `git clone git@github.com:reactioncommerce/reaction-platform.git`
2. `cd reaction-platform`
3. `make`

#### Versions

Node: 11.6.0
NPM: 6.5.0-next.0
Meteor Node: 8.9.3
Meteor NPM: 5.5.1
Reaction CLI: 0.29.0
Docker: 18.09.0

Comment: Might need to raise an issue with the authors... Can you run make with verbose option to get more detail? Are you missing some buikd tools? Does the directory `/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l` exist?

Comment: one thing i can tell is use Docker desktop app !  keep in on before making the project